# Problems exporting SVGs from AI into Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, svg, adobe-illustrator

I have an .ai in which I design all slides and layouts for an app I am working on.

When trying to export specific vector icons via

RMB > Export Selection > Android Format

and then entering Android Studio, trying to add a new Vector Asset like this:

RMB > New > Vector Asset > Local file > selecting the just exported SVG

I get an error message saying "In Asset 6.svg: ERROR@ line 1 defs is not supported" and the Vector Drawable Preview is completely blacked out. The asset becomes unusable within Android Studio.

I cannot test this on other IDEs so whether I am making a mistake while exporting from AI, or whether it is related to Android Studio, I cannot yet confirm. I hope you guys have any idea.

Comment: Try running your SVG through one of the online convertes [such as this one](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/).  Another thing you could try is to load your SVG into Inkscape and save it out as Simple SVG.

Comment: i had this problem from CorelDraw to Android vector asset importing . then i find the solution : try to convert your SVG exported to vector with this tool : https://shapeshifter.design/  if it's resolved your problem tell me to make it as a answer